# Scrolling Window Scrolls on Mouseover

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css, dhtml

Essentially, it is supposed to be a scrolling iFrame, that, once it hits the bottom, resets to the top. These functions all work fine. However, (note that this is in an .asp file) I also need a function that, when the user mouses over the window, stops the scrolling. It works, but when the user mouses around on the window, not keeping their mouse still, the scrolling occurs, in fact, it even scrolls faster. Any suggestions?

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="intranet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style>
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var num2 = 3;
            function getheight() {
                console.log(num2);
                var myWidth = 0,
            myHeight = 0;
                if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
                    //Non-IE
                    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
                    myHeight = window.innerHeight;
                } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
                    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
                    myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                    myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
                } else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
                    //IE 4 compatible
                    myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                    myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
                }
                var scrolledtonum = window.pageYOffset + myHeight + 2;
                var heightofbody = document.body.offsetHeight;
                if (scrolledtonum >= heightofbody) {
                    window.scroll(0, 0);
                }
            }

            window.onscroll = getheight;

            function pageScroll() {
                num2 = 3;
                clearTimeout(scrolldelay);
                pageScroller();
            }
            function unpageScroll() { num2 = 0; }
            function pageScroller() {
                window.scrollBy(0, num2);
                scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroller()', num);
            }
            var num = 50;
            window.onmouseout = pageScroll;
            window.onmouseover = unpageScroll;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="pageScroller()">
    <p></p>
    <br />
    <p></p>
    <br />
    <div id="datacontainer" style="position:relative;width:100%;text-align:center;" onMouseover="unpageScroll" onMouseout="unpageScroll">

    <!-- ADD YOUR SCROLLER COMMENT INSIDE HERE--------------------->
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1">
    <br>
    <center>
    <font size=2>
<!-- CONTENT-->
<!-- Closing tags --->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple script seems to work, perhaps you can deduce from it how to alter your script: http://jsfiddle.net/xkuZF/1/.

```
function func() {
    document.body.scrollTop++;
}

document.body.onmouseover = function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
};

document.body.onmouseout = function() {
    interval = setInterval(func);
};

var interval = setInterval(func);
```

Comment: I have an error when I run it: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmouseout' of null` - Any ideas?

Comment: @Guy: That would mean `document.body` is `null` (very unlikely - is that possible in your scenario?). What if you use `document.onmouseout`?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is. What would indicate so? Note that I am using script in an iFrame, would that make a difference on which code I should use? Also note that the page is asp.

Comment: @Guy: The `document` should just be accessible, not sure what's happening then...

Comment: I got it working - I deleted the body in the code. How would I make this slower?

Comment: @Guy: That seems to work too, does this fiddle work for you too? http://jsfiddle.net/xkuZF/2/

Comment: It does work. Do you have any ideas on how to make it slower?

Comment: @Guy: I forgot to include the interval time. The interval is called every 30 milliseconds in this example, so you can change the interval time: http://jsfiddle.net/xkuZF/5/.